# Power-Automate - How to use the output of a CSV table to add multiple rows into an existing Excel File?

Tags: excel, powerbi, export-to-csv, power-automate

I currently have a working scheduled flow in Power-Automate that is refreshing the dataset of a PowerBi report, running a query against it to return a table, then that table is then used to create a CSV table, which I'm currently using to create a new .csv file on OneDrive. Is it possible to, instead of creating a new file, I use this generated CSV table to add multiple rows to an existing Excel file on OneDrive?

I'm open to other suggestions for a different type of output file, instead of Excel, but each branch of the flow should update its unique file, instead of creating a new one every time.

I have tried to use the "Add a row" function instead of 'Creating a File', with an existing Excel file, but it hasn't worked very well. In my attempts, it has either create just one row, or added the entire CSV table to just one cell in the Excel file.[image: Current working-flow].

Update1: I've run the flow as suggested, and went to see the output, the details show the content/type as Json [image: Raw Output Window]. However, when I try to add the results of this step directly to an "add row in a table" step, no dynamic content is shown. [image: Add a row into a table step]

Comment: I assume the query returns JSON, would that be right? If so, skip the step of transforming to CSV and use that to add rows to a table.

Comment: The query returns a table, it is basically a 
DEFINE
VAR _table = SUMMARIZE (data, variable1, variable2, etc.)
EVALUATE _table.

When I skip transforming to CSV, no dynamic content is shown as an option for the "Add a row to a table" step.

Comment: But what is a table? Is it JSON or tab delimited or HTML or XML or something else altogether? You need to show what it gives you.

Comment: @Skin, I'm sorry, but I don't know what u mean... I'm running a DAX query against the dataset, it's pretty much just an EVALUATE statement, I don't know which of these types you mentioned it returns, or if it is any of them at all, I just did it based on this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/evaluate-statement-dax. It is supposed to just return a table with the filter and summarization I set. Then, I've tried to use the "Create a CSV table" because with the table from the EVALUATE query, it wasn't showing any dynamic content for the "Add a row to Excel" step.

Comment: When you run the flow, the run a query step must return something back to you. Usually, it’s in the form of a json document but the best way for you to tell is, go to a completed run, click on that step and get the output. If I can see that output, I’ll likely be able to help you.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Skin, I added an update to the question as you suggested

Comment: That’s just the headers of the response, sorry but that doesn’t help. Isn’t there a body to that response with all of the data? It says the content length is 27436 so there must be a body. Also, in future, please post the json text, not an image.